A possible parameter transformation to continuous time in a research paper?
I am reading a paper where the Volume is described, using a simple diffusion model:
$$
d\tilde{V}_t = \mu_V dt + \sigma_V dW_t
$$
When they estimate the volume diffusion process parameters, they use the following equation and get the parameters $\mu_v, \sigma_v$
$$
\Delta \tilde{V}_t = \mu_V \Delta t + \epsilon_t,
$$
$$
\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \delta_V^2).
$$
It is not written in the paper whether they used a parameter transformation to continuous time. Could you help me if they applied a parameter transformation and if so, how to derive it?
Link to paper
